# BUG: Downloads from Google Cloud Storage console browser name incorrectly (full path)

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Apologies if this is wrong forum, but Google points you here for problems and support.  If there's a better place to report a bug, let me know.

In the last week or so the Google Cloud Storage browser (https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser) has started incorrectly naming downloaded files.  When you download a file "/path/to/my/file.xyz" the filename now includes the full file path.

In Chrome the file:

```
/path/to/my/file.xyz
```

will be downloaded as:

```
path%2fto%2fmy%2ffile.xyz
```

Results in other browsers are similar, but Firefox and safari escape the %2f as "-" in the downloaded file.

Comment: Can you clarify what the old filename used to be?

Comment: There is no old filename as such.  In the case above, I'd expect the filename when downloaded be `file.xyz`.   If you create any file in any nested path in Google Cloud Storage the console browser will download the file with the full path with the slashes encoded in a browser specific way.